# Typescript how to change click event of a checkbox to another handler

Tags: angular, typescript

Suppose i have a two div, the left div contain all items with checkbox, and the right one is empty,but on click of plus button of each item of left div i have a click handler that remove the selected item from left div, and change some attributes of that element and add on right div, now alongside of other attributes i should change click event of added items of right div to another handler:
[image]

click event of left side items with plus icon is mapped to a function named `(click)='addItem($event)'`, in this function i remove the target element from left div, and change some attributes like `checked=true, and fa-plus to fa-minus`, but i need to change its click handler to another function `removeItem($event)`.
what i have tried:

```
 addItem(itemId) {
    const element = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById(itemId);
    element.checked = true;
    const itemsWrapper = <HTMLInputElement> 
    document.getElementById('item4select');
    const selectedItemWrapper = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById('selectedItems');
    const selectedItem = itemsWrapper.querySelector('li[data="'+itemId+'"]');

    itemsWrapper.removeChild(selectedItem);

    selectedItem.setAttribute('data', 'sel_'+itemId)
    selectedItem.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').setAttribute('id', 'sel_'+itemId);
    // Bellow two line are for changing click event.
    //selectedItem.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').click = 'removeMe($event)';

  //selectedItem.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').setAttribute('click', 'removeMe($event)');

selectedItem.querySelector('span[refLabel="addItemBtn"]').classList.remove('fa-plus');
  selectedItem.querySelector('span[refLabel="addItemBtn"]').classList.add('fa-minus');
selectedItemWrapper.appendChild(selectedItem);
this.checkAllOfSelectedItemsChecked = true;
this.checkAllOfSelectedItemsClass = 'fa-check-square';

}
```

Comment: You're doing it completely wrong. Don't do DOM manipulation. Just have two arrays of objects (representing elements of your divs) in your controller, and remove/add elements from/to the arrays on click. Use ngFor in your templates to display the contents of the two arrays.

Comment: May i know why you are using javascript inside typescript.Instead make it as two array left and right whenever you click left check box add the item to right array when uncheck remove from right array

Comment: See a simple example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/dGZw2kQOcSsiaem0gajR?p=preview

Comment: @jbnizet thank you have pointed the my mistake, and show the right way